# OIOSAML .NET dk.nita.saml20.identity.Saml20Identity.Current is always null

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0

I have created login.ashx handler with this code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   var handler = new dk.nita.saml20.protocol.Saml20SignonHandler();
   handler.ProcessRequest(context);
}
```

I'm redirected to a login form where I insert my username and password. After that I get redirected back to my web app but `dk.nita.saml20.identity.Saml20Identity.Current` is null..

I have used SAML Tracer to show SAMLResponse and everything looks good. It seems I'm missing something. My app does not process that SAML response. What am I doing wrong?

I have added Federation and SAML20Federation section to web.config.

Here is my Federation section

```
<Federation xmlns="urn:dk.nita.saml20.configuration">
   <SigningCertificate findValue="CN=WORK-PC" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" validonly="no"/>
   <!-- The list of allowed audiences must at least contain the id of the service provider. -->
   <AllowedAudienceUris>
     <Audience>5F73859A-EDFF-47A8-B348-D46C9ED34C2B</Audience>
   </AllowedAudienceUris>
</Federation>

<SAML20Federation xmlns="urn:dk.nita.saml20.configuration">
  <ShowError>true</ShowError>
  <ServiceProvider id="5F73859A-EDFF-47A8-B348-D46C9ED34C2B" server="https://fed-lab.aaiedu.hr/">
    <ServiceEndpoint localpath="login.ashx" type="signon" redirectUrl="http://localhost:12771/logout" index="0"/>
    <ServiceEndpoint localpath="logout.ashx" type="logout" redirectUrl="Home.aspx" index="1"/>
    <ServiceEndpoint localpath="metadata.ashx" type="metadata"/>
    <md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
      <md:Company>Demo</md:Company>
      <md:GivenName>Ivan</md:GivenName>
      <md:SurName>Horvat</md:SurName>
      <md:EmailAddress>email@demo.hr</md:EmailAddress>
      <md:TelephoneNumber>1111111</md:TelephoneNumber>
    </md:ContactPerson>
    <NameIDFormats all="true"/>
    </ServiceProvider>
<RequestedAttributes>
<!-- The attributes that the demonstration identity provider issues. -->
<att name="urn:FirstName" isRequired="true"/>
<att name="urn:LastName" isRequired="true"/>
<att name="urn:Age"/>
</RequestedAttributes>
<IDPEndPoints metadata="C:\metadata\">
<add id="https://fed-lab.aaiedu.hr/ms/saml2/idp/metadata.php">
<CertificateValidation>
<add type="dk.nita.saml20.Specification.SelfIssuedCertificateSpecification, dk.nita.saml20"/>
</CertificateValidation>
</add>
</IDPEndPoints>
</SAML20Federation>
```

and I system web I have

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="login.ashx"  name="ServiceProvider"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Did you solve it? I don't remember what was the problem but looking at the code I've changed ServiceEndpoint path from localpath="login.ashx" to localpath="~/login.ashx"

Comment: Yes, but the problem in my case was at the SAML server, not in my application